# Oracle regexp_replace every occurence

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

I want to replace the every occurrence of String except for the first occurrence, using `regexp_replace`. Below query will replace only second occurrence.

```
select 'This is test STRING STRING some text STRING some more text'
  from dual 

select regexp_replace('This is test STRING STRING some text STRING some more text',
                      'STRING',
                      'REPLACED-STRING' ,
                      1,
                      2)
  from dual
```

Results is,

> This is test STRING REPLACED-STRING some text STRING some more text

But I need result like this.

> This is test STRING REPLACED-STRING some text REPLACED-STRING some more text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) in combination with [`REGEXP_INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm). The idea is to replace **all** occurences using `REGEXP_REPLACE` beginning at position `REGEXP_INSTR` returns (here you specify that it should return the second occurence of your search string).

This snippet illustrates the idea:

```
regexp_replace(
  'This is test STRING STRING some text STRING some more text',
  'STRING',
  'REPLACED-STRING', 
  regexp_instr(
    'This is test STRING STRING some text STRING some more text',
    'STRING',
    1,2,1
  ), 
  0
)
```

Note: Please understand this only as a starter - I know that it can be optimized (and should be). I hope it helped a bit ;-)
*Jost

Comment: Thanks. Was able to do  by modifying to         select regexp_replace(
  'This is test STRING STRING some text STRING some more text',
  'STRING',
  'REPLACED-STRING', 
  regexp_instr(
    'This is test STRING STRING some text STRING some more text',
    'STRING',
    1
  )+6, 
  0
) from dual